# How to set the size of ShareableList list in multiprocessing.shared_memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, memoryview

I defined a `ShareableList()` to store strings in it by using the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

global_memory = shared_memory.ShareableList([""] * 10, name='my_mem')

global_memory[0] = "hello I'm a long string"
```

It returns:

```py
ValueError: bytes/str item exceeds available storage
```

I expected this because in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) example the same happened:

```py
>>> from multiprocessing import shared_memory

>>> a = shared_memory.ShareableList(['howdy', b'HoWdY', -273.154, 100, None, True, 42])

>>> [ type(entry) for entry in a ]
[<class 'str'>, <class 'bytes'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>]

>>> a[2]
-273.154

>>> a[2] = -78.5

>>> a[2]
-78.5

>>> a[2] = 'dry ice'  # Changing data types is supported as well

>>> a[2]
'dry ice'

>>> a[2] = 'larger than previously allocated storage space'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: exceeds available storage for existing str

>>> a[2]
'dry ice'

len(a)
7

a.index(42)
6

a.count(b'howdy')
0

a.count(b'HoWdY')
1

a.shm.close()

a.shm.unlink()

del a  # Use of a ShareableList after call to unlink() is unsupported
```

But my question is, how to add more space for every element in the list, so I can store larger strings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, so I checked the source code of `ShareableList`.

When you declare the `sequence` parameter of `ShareableList`, your `global_memory` will apply for a certain amount of memory, and the size of this memory cannot be changed.

So, if you want to store a larger string later, you should give a larger initial value ([less than 10M bytes each](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html)) when initializing the `sequence` parameter.

for example:

```py
ShareableList([' ' * 256, ' ' * 512, ' ' * 1024])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).